# Read JSON in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I need to be able to process a JSON response.  I don't want to hardcode the array position in case they change, so something like this is out of the question:

```
@activity('Place Details').output.result.components[2].name
```

How can I get the name `123` where `types = number` given a JSON array like below:

```
"result": {
    "components": [
        {
            "name": "ABC",
            "types": [
                "alphabet"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "123",
            "types": [
                "number"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any other compute in your architecture, Azure SQL DB, Databricks, Spark etc as this could influence the decision.  What’s the source and target?

Comment: No it's just a very simple pipeline in ADF, literally just one web activity that calls the API followed by a Lookup activity to handle the response in SSMS.  I know I can probably just get the whole response and then use OPENJSON somehow so that's an option, but wondered if there was a simpler option that can handle all that in ADF still before it gets to SSMS.

Comment: Have you tried using a dataflow activity? You could create a dataflow that first flattens the JSON and then filters for what you're looking for.

Comment: Have tried using mapping dataflow in the past and not really a fan, finds it quite slow to be honest but could visit that as a last resort

Answer (score 0):

One example using the `OPENJSON` method:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{
    "result": {
        "components": [
            {
                "name": "ABC",
                "types": [
                    "alphabet"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "123",
                "types": [
                    "number"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}'

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE( o.[value], '$.name' ) [name],
    JSON_VALUE( o.[value], '$.types[0]' ) [types]
FROM OPENJSON( @json, '$.result.components' ) o
)
SELECT [name]
FROM cte 
WHERE types = 'number'
```

I will have a look at other methods.